# Reference after posting data from web worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I thought that the serialisation of objects you send with 'postMessage' from a web worker is made with JSON.serialize and the deserialisation with JSON.parse.
But I made a test (in Firefox) with that worker code:

```
function A() {
    this.id = 3;
    this.save;
}

var a1 = new A();
var a2 = new A();

a1.save = a2;

postMessage({
    'a1' : a1,
    'a2' : a2    
});
```

Now in the main file you have that:

```
w.onmessage = function(event) {
    event.data.a2.id = 7;
};
```

The thing is that the value in a1.save.id is also 7 after that.
So there must be a reference but when you use JSON.serialze and JSON.parse there is no reference...
So how is the serialisation made? Can I assume that reference in all Browsers?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Worker communication does not use JSON for serialisation. You could do manually and pass strings, but you don't need to.

[MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers#Passing_data):

> Messages passed between the main page and workers are copied, not shared. Objects are serialized as they're handed to the worker, and subsequently, de-serialized on the other end. The page and worker do not share the same instance, so the end result is that a duplicate is created on each end. Most browsers implement this feature as [structured cloning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/The_structured_clone_algorithm).

In fact, the [Worker spec for `postMessage`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/workers/#dom-dedicatedworkerglobalscope-postmessage) says that the arguments are passed to the underlying `MessagePort`'s `postMessage`, and [that one is specified](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#dom-messageport-postmessage) to use the [structured cloning algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#safe-passing-of-structured-data) on the `message` argument.